# How can I change the style in .jumbotron h1 font family

Tags: css, wordpress

I bought a ready made theme for WordPress and changed the h1 typeface from sans serif to times but it is still in bold style. Can someone guide me to change the style to regular italic please?

Both WordPress and bought themes are quite new to me quite new to me. 4 posts to the author has only resulted in being able to change the font despite asking for documentation, I don't think there is any. How hard could it be to send me 2 lines of code?

It looks like a — Pay your money and roll the dice support system.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A theme developer can't be expected to provide free support for doing development work. The fee you pay includes support for issues with the shipped theme, not functionality beyond that. In any case, we can't help you without seeing code. Best guess: `font-weight: 400; font-style: italic;`

Comment: Well thank you for your views Mevius, Wordpress themes (the ones that cost $100+ AUD) usually have a CSS/Javascript module where you can change items like fonts for h1, h2, h3 etc. Providing documentation on how to use this method of altering CSS in WordPress is supposed to be contained in the documentation provided with the theme. When (ThemeForest) require authors to provide 6 month's support and the Author fails to do this, the contravene a contract they agreed to.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `important` flag, that might override the theme styles. It looks like this:

```
font-weight: 400 !important;
font-style: italic !important;
```

Pay attention to how you target the element as well. Try targeting just `.jumbotron {}` and/or `.jumbotron h1 {}`. I can't say which will work without seeing the HTML but play around with targeting the element a few different ways, one of them should work.

Comment: Thank you Kristy, That worked. I have now replaced the offensively bold Google font the author used with a standard 'Times' Italic font.

This makes the page load faster too because the font (Typeface) is part of all computers basic fonts. No calls to another website for fonts. _italic_ Wedding Directory in times sure looks better than in an ultra bold sans serif Helvetica + font from Google. I think the over use of Google fonts in any application that also makes MSQL calls to load noticeably slows down the whole site. 
Thanks again Ryadia.

Comment: No problem! Since my answer was correct, can you mark it as accepted? Here's info about how to do that - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I've no idea how to do this Kristy. The link you pointed me to only explain the purpose of accepting an answer, not how to accept it. Why not write to the forum admin and complain?